# Margin-top não empurra div para baixo

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando aplicar um margin em uma div e de nenhuma forma funciona.

Tenho meu HTML:

```
<div class="side-menu-user-infos">
    <div class="side-menu-user-photo">
        <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/user-png-icon-male-user-icon-512.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

E meu CSS:

```
.side-menu-user-infos {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 190px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.side-menu-user-photo {  
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

O resultado disso é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu queria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nenhum tipo de margin funciona, onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode trocar o `margin: 0 auto;` por `margin: 30px auto 0 auto;`. Quando o `margin` possui apenas 2 valores, o primeiro é do *top* e *bottom* e o segundo do *right* e *left*.

Fazendo a troca por `margin: 30px auto 0 auto;`, note que agora o `margin` possui 4 valores:

```
            right  left
              ↓      ↓
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
         ↑        ↑
        top    bottom
```

Aí você ajusta o `30px` (que seria o *margin-top*) pelo valor que quiser.

Poderia também ser apenas com 3 valores:

```
         right/left
              ↓      ↓
margin: 30px auto 0;
         ↑        ↑
        top    bottom
```

Quando possui 3 valores, o primeiro é do *top*, o segundo do *right* e *left* e o terceiro do *bottom*.

Mas você poderia também, deixar `margin: 0 auto;` e após (somente após) colocar `margin-top: 30px`, porque o `margin-top` irá sobrepor o valor referente ao *top* do `margin: 0 auto;`:

```
.side-menu-user-photo {  
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
}
```

**Veja exemplo:**

```css
.side-menu-user-infos {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 190px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.side-menu-user-photo {  
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu-user-infos">
    <div class="side-menu-user-photo">
        <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/user-png-icon-male-user-icon-512.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam
Já me ajudou mais de uma vez :), obrigado! Preciso ler um pouco mais sobre a utilização dos valores que podem ser atribuidos nas tags!

Comment: Tmj amigo! ;)))

Answer (score 1):

Tenta trocar a margin para padding.

```
.side-menu-user-infos {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 190px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
  position: relative;
  **padding: 15px auto;**
}

.side-menu-user-photo {  
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
   **padding: 15px auto;**
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```